# Get data attribute from html before calling API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component to load blog articles to insert inside a CMS.
I will be getting an author name from a data-name attribute from html.
When I run this code with url2 (hard coded name of the author) everything works. When I run the code with url1 (name of author read from data-attribute) nothing works. Please help.

I have this html:

```
<div id="dataElement" data-name="Peter Smith"></div>
```

And this is the code inside my react component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      insightsData: [],
      loading: true,
      authorName: document.getElementById('dataElement').getAttribute('data-name').replace(/ /g, "_")
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let self = this;

    let url2 = '/api/Insights/GetAuthorArticles?authorName=Peter_Smith&numRecords=5';
    let url1 = `/api/Insights/GetAuthorArticles?authorName=${this.state.authorName}&numRecords=5`;

    this.setState({loading:true});
    var Promise = require("es6-promise");
    Promise.polyfill();
    axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      self.setState({
        insightsData: response.data.InsightsResults.Records
      }, this.setState({loading:false}));
      console.log(response.data.InsightsResults.Records);
    });
  }
```

Comment: where comes from your element with attribute? does this come from your react app?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't really in the spirit of React (use state/props to render some HTML, and reflect UI changes back to state). Here it looks like you're approaching this from a traditional HTML/JS mindset (use JS to grab some HTML and process it) which won't work well in the long-term. Store the name in state to begin with and generate the HTML (if you need to) using that data.

Comment: @duc mai The html element is not loaded in React, it's loaded in CMS. The HTML should be loaded before it calls the javascript file that loads a React component with an API call. I just need to get data from that html element into React somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The html is loaded only after the constructor. Try this, using [react ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      insightsData: [],
      loading: true,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let self = this;

    let url2 = '/api/Insights/GetAuthorArticles?authorName=Peter_Smith&numRecords=5';
    let url1 = `/api/Insights/GetAuthorArticles?authorName=${document.getElementById('dataElement').getAttribute('data-name').replace(/ /g, "_")}&numRecords=5`;

    this.setState({loading:true});
    var Promise = require("es6-promise");
    Promise.polyfill();
    axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      self.setState({
        insightsData: response.data.InsightsResults.Records
      }, this.setState({loading:false}));
      console.log(response.data.InsightsResults.Records);
    });
  }
```

EDIT: solution without ref.

Comment: it could be a solution but if the element is rendered by react so why not store the author name in a state. If the element is not rendered by react so your solution may not work

Comment: @SagiRika The html element is not loaded in React, it's loaded in CMS. The HTML should be loaded before it calls the javascript file that loads a React component with an API call. I just need to get data with author name from that html element into React somehow.

Comment: Editted to a solution w/o refs. let me know if it helps. @blueberry

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="dataElement" data-name="Peter Smith"></div>` gets mounted after the constructor. you will never have `dataElement` in the dom when you run `authorName: document.getElementById('dataElement')...`

try moving `authorName: document.getElementById('dataElement')...` to `componentDidMount` using `setState` and `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`

Here are the docs, if you wanna deep dive. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting